# Как использовать одну форму и для регистрации и для редактирования пользователя.

Tags: аутентификация, model, формы, ruby-on-rails

Пользователь может, зарегистрировавшись, отредактировать свой профиль. Для редактирования профиля используется та же форма что и для регистрации. Но при редактировании профиля пользователю приходится так же вводить пароль и его подтверждение. А если профиль редактирует не он сам, а администратор, то ему тоже прийдётся вводить пароль, который он, понятное дело, не знает. Так вот, что нужно сделать чтобы этого избежать?

> **P.S.** модель контроллер и отображение сгенерированы
> скаффолдингом.

Comment: У юзера есть метод role? такого вида current_user.role.eql?("admin")

Comment: Такого метода нету, есть поле is_stuff:boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать популярное решение [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). У девайса метод *update_without_password*:

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update_without_password(params[:user])
      redirect_to root_url, flash[:notice] = "ok"
    else
      render action: "edit"
    end
   end
end
```

Либо написать свой приватный метод, который бы позволял апдейтить админу юзера без пароля.

Comment: Можно поподробнее об установке девайса, а то, гем поставил метод поменял, выдаёт: 

    undefined method `update_without_password' for #<User:0x007fed947cc368>

Comment: 1. gem 'devise' > Gemfile
2. bundle install
3. rails generate devise:install
4. подробности тут https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: Можете унаследовать девайсовский: class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

Comment: Сделал проще, взял метод из Device и приделал его к своей модели, но теперь валидация не даёт сохранить, т. к. пишет, что пароль не может быть пустым или короче 6 символов что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: За 6 символов отвечает :validatable
Метод update_without_password используете?

Comment: Ну, как бы, да, только в свою модель его из исходников девайса взял...